# Custom newfrom (upload a picture and fill in the picture url)

Tags: list, javascript, client-object-model

I have to customize an announcement list new and edit form.

In the form is there is a Picture Colum. But I don’t want the user to go first to a picture library, upload the picture, copy the picture url and fill in the url in the announcement list form.

In the Internet I found this helping jScript (http://spimagefieldupload.codeplex.com/).

//If the link is clicked, show the existing RteUploadDialog.aspx page as a popup

```
      var dialog = {url: SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl("RteUploadDialog.aspx") + "?LCID=" + SP.Res.lcid + "&Dialog=UploadImage&UseDivDialog=true&Source=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location),
            allowMaximize: true,
            showClose: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 160,
            dialogReturnValueCallback: function (success, html) {
                if (success) {
                    //Gets the picture's url from the popup, shows it and hides the links
                    var $emptyPanel = jQuery("#" + selectorId + "_EmptyPanel");
                    var $assetSelectedPanel = jQuery("#" + selectorId + "_AssetSelectedPanel");
                    var $imageFieldDisplay = jQuery("#" + selectorId + "_ImageFieldDisplay");
                    $imageFieldDisplay.html(html);
                    $emptyPanel.css("display", "none");
                    $assetSelectedPanel.css("display", "inline");
                }
            }
        };
        thisDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialog);
```

But how i can change the script (dialogReturnValueCallback: function) so that the picture url and the picture name is stored in jScript Variables in the form. So I can write I back in the form fileds.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I used a plain single line textbox named "Feature Image" to achieve this.  I also added in a "Test Link" hyperlink for users to verify the image was uploaded correctly.  Code below:

```
 //If the link is clicked, show the existing RteUploadDialog.aspx page as a popup
    var dialog = {
        url: SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl("RteUploadDialog.aspx") + "?LCID=" + SP.Res.lcid + "&Dialog=UploadImage&UseDivDialog=true&Source=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location),
        allowMaximize: true,
        showClose: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 160,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: function (success, html) {
            if (success) {
                //Gets the picture's url from the popup, shows it and hides the links
                $("input[Title$='Feature Image']").val(thisSite + "/" + html.substring(11,html.indexOf("alt") - 2));
                var tagId = $("input[Title$='Feature Image']").attr("id");
                var testLinkDiv = "<div id=\"testFeaturedImage\" Title=\"Test Image\" style=\"color:black; float:right\"><a href=\"" +
                    "javascript:TestURL('" + tagId + "');\">Test Image Link" +"</a></div>";
                $(testLinkDiv).insertAfter($('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Feature Image")').parent('tr'));
            }
        }
    };

    $("input[Title$='Feature Image']").focus(function(){
        $('#testFeaturedImage').hide();
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            //Featured Image is blank, enable click to add
            thisDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialog);
        }
        else{
            var imgIndex = -1;
            var tagId = $(this).attr("id");
            //A value exists in the featured image textbox.  Allow user to test
            var testLinkDiv = "<div id=\"testFeaturedImage\" Title=\"Test Image\" style=\"color:black; float:right\"><a href=\"" +
                "javascript:TestURL('" + tagId + "');\">Test Image Link" +"</a></div>";
            $(testLinkDiv).insertAfter($('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Feature Image")').parent('tr'));
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $('#testFeaturedImage').hide();
        }
    });
```